# Check whethere an array contain element

Tags: swift

I wonder why following not working:

```
var tmp = [AnyObject] ()
for (key, value) in dictionary{

        if (tmp.contains(value)){

        } 
      tmp.append(value as AnyObject)
    }
```

Look like there is no method .contain for an Array. it force me to use some other method  `tmp.contains(where: <#T##(AnyObject) throws -> Bool#>)`

But i dont want to. I simply want to check whether an array contain that specific object!

Comment: How is the dictionary defined? What kind of values does it contain?  Do you have to use `AnyObject`?

Comment: @MartinR function defined as func isInvertible (inDict dictionary: [String : Int]) -> Bool, therefore dictionary contain Int as value.

Comment: Then the easiest solution would be to define the array as `var tmp = [Int]()`

Comment: @MartinR yes cool, but it is study case, in real world situation i will have totally no idea of what will be inside that array, what is the purpose of using such language as Swift then? If you could do the same in Obj-C without pain.

Comment: You don't have `[String : Int]`  dictionaries in Objective-C. In Obj-C, both keys and values are subclasses of NSObject (and that would work in Swift as well).

Comment: @MartinR i ended up with var tmp = [AnyHashable] (), but can i be sure that any object (for example, that come from json) will conform to that protocol?

Comment: alternatively, you can use NSObect such as: `var tmp = [NSObject]()`
`var dictionary: [Int: NSObject] = [1: "Hello1" as NSObject, 2: "Hello2" as NSObject, 3: "Hello3" as NSObject, 4: false as NSObject, 5: 289 as NSObject ]`, and then you can  discard `as AnyHashable` in the `for-in loop`...

Comment: That would work for any type of object for sure!

Comment: @Xcoder123 ok, cool, but i though that using NS-classes is some kind of wrong coding on Swift,  isn't that so?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban I still recommend the solution presented in the answer, but `NS` Data types are not necessarily "wrong" in swift

Comment: Since there is no equivalent to the **N**ext **S**tep **Object**, besides for **AnyObject**, which in this case is the cause of the question. Though, some may argue a lot over this, I'm not that of an opponent of NS based classes

Comment: @Xcoder123 thank you for your explanation, i wish i could stay with old good Obj-C..

Comment: SO, why don't you?? It just feels like you're a keen disliker of Swift :)))

Comment: @Xcoder123 i dont see benefits of this logic, all this checks i can simply do with Obj-C as well, without struggling like that :) Instead of using NSObject in Swift you better would use Obj-C then)

Comment: That's 100 % up to you. Good Luck!

Comment: @Xcoder123 yes thanks, same there :)

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban (about your comment: "i though that using NS-classes is some kind of wrong coding on Swift") - `NSObject` is not a bridged type from Objective-C. To make understand what I mean, please refer to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html). Besides for `NSObject` and only a few other `NS` types, you should not use `NS` prefixed types, because they're `Foundation` types "Bridged from Objective-C" (e.g.: never use `NSString` in Swift without a very good reason)

Comment: I posted this comment to avoid confusion on this quite fragile topic referring to `NS` types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend switching from `AnyObject` to `AnyHashable`(of course if that's possible), because `AnyHashable` is **[Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable)**. Your code would look like this:

```
var tmp = [AnyHashable]()
var dictionary: [Int: Any] = [1: "Hello1", 2: "Hello2", 3: "Hello3", 4: false, 5: 289 ]
for (key, value) in dictionary{
    if tmp.contains(value as! AnyHashable){
         continue
    }
    tmp.append(value as! AnyHashable)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

That's because AnyObject is not an Equatable object. If you have an AnyObject array, you have to do the comparisons yourself. If you used an array of Strings or a custom class for instance you could use [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641180-contains) contains() method of Sequence